# ASP.NET - Server.Transfer with url in browser updated

Tags: asp.net, http, httpresponse, response.redirect, server.transfer

I am not sure if I will be able to explain this clearly.

I have a page on the website, lets say `www.example.com/mypage/`

Due to some business reason I would like to redirect the user to another page in the same website, say `www.example.com/myotherpage/` as soon as the user enters `www.example.com/mypage/` on the browser and hits go (I mean there is no referred url from which I can maintain any state).

`Response.Redirect` works just fine but due to the round trips it takes one hell of a time to load.

If I use `Server.Transfer` the loading time reduces significantly (less than half the time taken for `Response.Redirect`) but the url remains as it is i.e. `www.example.com/mypage/`.

My client would like to see the url of the new page in the browser i.e. `www.example.com/myotherpage/`.

On googling a little I found `window.history.pushState` (given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)) but this is only applicable to latest browsers.

Also I need this on a mobile device so not sure if this code will work there.

I tried to search on the internet of any better ideas but not able to find one.

Any ideas will be of great help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not simply use <httpRedirect ...> in your web.config?

Comment: A redirect should be almost no slower than opening the target page directly. If `due to the round trips it takes one hell of a time to load` then you may need to look at a better hosting solution, or perhaps pity your users for having such bad connections. Just one last thing that may help: make sure you do no unnecessary processing before the `Response.Redirect` is reached.

Comment: I think httpRedirect will always redirect the said url. I do not want that. As mentioned in the question there is a business reason. Only when the reason is satisfied I would like to redirect else show the same page.

Comment: @PeterB; the time observed is from 1 machine only and that too on the same network as the server. That is the reason I was able to comment on time difference between `Response.Redirect` and `Server.Transfer`. A request if you can elaborate on `hosting solutions`? I dont think there is any heavy processing before `Response.Redirect`

Comment: A redirect itself is very fast, it should add no more than some milliseconds when on the same network. There might be a few things that can make it slower: (1) the server (webpage) takes time to process whatever before it decides to redirect, or (2) the server is overloaded / underdimensioned for its purpose, so either the initial page or the new page (or even both) react slow because of that.

Comment: One final addition: try doing `Response.Clear()` before the `Response.Redirect()`. That will clear the buffer, so no unneeded HTML is sent along with the Redirect. If that makes a difference then you need to look into why there is so much HTML to begin with, when it clearly isn't needed and should not have been generated.

Comment: @PeterB; let me try out the `Response.Clear()` thing. Will update you tomorrow.

Comment: @PeterB; `Response.Clear()` not increasing the speed. Any thoughts around having the new url on the browser after `Server.Transfer`?

Comment: That's not possible. With Server.Transfer, only the server is aware that another page gets executed, the browser sees just the output. Have you tried [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what traffic (requests & responses) is going over the line in all situations? Other than that, I'm afraid I can't help any further.